# Как передать загрузчику (file-loader) путь к файлу?

Tags: webpack

Хочу переложить картинки из исходников в директорию сборки, сохраняя относительные пути. Пока настроено вот так.

```
{ 
  test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/,
  use: [
         {
           loader: "file-loader",
           options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: 'img/',
                      publicPath: 'img/'
                    }
         }
       ]
}
```

Разумеется, всё падает кучей. А как сказать загрузчику, чтобы он взял нужный кусок пути у исходника?

Comment: Что значит нужный кусок у исходника? можно пример?

Comment: файл \folder\folder\src\img\folder\image-1.jpg перенести в папку build с путём, который у неё был относительно папки src.
Не кусок исходника, а "нужный кусок пути у исходника".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть ряд плейсхолдеров. Например: [path] - относительный путь, а [ext] - расширение. Данный пример 
    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
создаст в 'output' файл с тем же путём, что был у оригинала относительно папки 'context', которая по умолчанию есть расположение 'entry'. Так же 'context' можно указать загрузчику вручную.
Так же сработает такая комбинация:

```
{
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]',
                  useRelativePath: true
             }
}
```